# Вывести последние семь дней календаря

Tags: javascript, дата

Хочу сделать диаграмму активности пользователя за прошедшие 7 дней календаря. Никак не могу сообразить как это сделать. Нужно получить массив дат начиная с текущей даты т.е `[31.03.2018, 30.03.2018, 29.03.2018 т.д]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
let now = new Date();

let time = now.getTime();
now = new Date(time - (time % 86400000));

let arr = [];
let arr2 = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++, now.setDate(now.getDate() - 1)) {
  arr.push(new Date(now.getTime()));
  arr2.push(now.getDate() + '.' + (now.getMonth() + 1) + "." + now.getFullYear());
}

console.log(arr2);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: wow а можно только дату. Спасибо)

Comment: @AziretKadykeev так и сделано, часы отрезаются

Comment: `Sat Mar 31 2018 06:00:00 GMT+0600 (Центральная Азия (зима))` выводится такое, а мне надо просто дату

Comment: Это просто вывод функции `console.log` стандартное преобразование даты в строку, вы можете себе вывести в любом формате, сейчас добавлю код.

Comment: @AziretKadykeev добавил приведение к строчкам вида `yyyy.MM.dd`

Answer (score 3):

```js
/**
 *
 * @param {Number} _n
 * @param {String} _date
 */
function getA(_n,_date) {
  let now = (_date)
    ? new Date(_date)
    : new Date
  let y = now.getFullYear()
  let m = now.getMonth()
  let d = now.getDate()

  let arr = []
  for (var i = 0; i < _n; i++) {
    let date = new Date
    
    /**
      * Sets the year of the Date object using local time.
      * @param year A numeric value for the year.
      * @param month A zero-based numeric value for the month (0 for January, 11 for December). Must be specified if numDate is specified.
      * @param date A numeric value equal for the day of the month.
      */
    date.setFullYear(y,m,d - i)

    // -->
    let res1 = date.toLocaleDateString()
    // <--

    // -->
    let y2 = date.getFullYear()
    let m2 = date.getMonth()
    m2++ // ©month A zero-based numeric value for the month (0 for January, 11 for December).
    let d2 = date.getDate()
    if((''+m2).length===1){
      m2 = '0'+m2 // добавить ноль в начале
    }
    if((''+d2).length===1){
      d2 = '0'+d2 // добавить ноль в начале
    }
    let res2 = [
      y2,
      m2,
      d2,
    ].join('-')// разделитель
    // <--
    arr.push(res1+'    или    '+res2)
  }
  return arr
}

window.addEventListener('load',() => {
  let div = document.createElement('div')

  getA(7,'01.04.2018').forEach(_str => {
    div.innerHTML += '<br>' + _str
  })
  div.innerHTML += '<br>'

  getA(7,'2018 01 04').forEach(_str => {
    div.innerHTML += '<br>' + _str
  })
  div.innerHTML += '<br>'

  getA(7).forEach(_str => {
    div.innerHTML += '<br>' + _str
  })

  document.body.appendChild(div)
})
```

подробнее почитать можно тут:
https://learn.javascript.ru/datetime
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date